# Grunt: Loading dependencies takes several minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I've put together a few pretty standard grunt tasks with a reasonable number of dependencies, but for some reason it takes 1-3 minutes to actually load the dependencies. I'm moderately new to grunt, but since most of the other questions about extreme slowness loading grunt dependencies cite times of a few seconds, I'm guessing I'm doing something very wrong.

Here's what my gruntfile looks like:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt);
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    const ignoredSourceScriptPatterns = ['!**/*.debug.js', '!**/*.min.js', '!scripts/*', '!**/*.map'],
        baseUIPath = 'presentation/ui',
        scripts = grunt.file.expand({filter: 'isFile',
            matchBase: true,
            cwd: baseUIPath},
        ['*.js', ...ignoredSourceScriptPatterns]);

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        copy: {
            build: {
                cwd: 'presentation/',
                src: 'ui/**',
                dest: path.join('presentation', 'static'),
                expand: true
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                compress: false
            },
            build: {
                cwd: baseUIPath,
                files: function() {
                    var modules = grunt.file.expand({
                            filter: 'isDirectory',
                            expand: true,
                            cwd: 'presentation/ui/modules'
                        }, ['**', '!**/css', '!**/scripts', ...ignoredSourceScriptPatterns]),
                        components = grunt.file.expand({
                            filter: 'isFile',
                            expand: true,
                            cwd: 'presentation/ui'
                        }, ['components/!*.js', ...ignoredSourceScriptPatterns]),
                        files, componentFiles;

                    files = modules.map(function(path) {
                        var modulePath = `modules/${path}/scripts`,
                            moduleName = modulePath.split('/').reduce(function(result, next) {
                                var nameFragment;

                                switch(next) {
                                case "modules":
                                    nameFragment = "Poptart.";
                                    break;
                                case "scripts":
                                    nameFragment = "min.js";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    nameFragment = `${next.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + next.slice(1)}.`;
                                    break;
                                }
                                return result + nameFragment;
                            }, "");

                        return {
                            src: grunt.file.expand({
                                filter: 'isFile'
                            }, [`${baseUIPath}/${modulePath}/*.js`, ...ignoredSourceScriptPatterns]).sort(
                                function(a, b) {
                                    return a.length - b.length;
                                }
                            ),
                            dest: `${baseUIPath}/${modulePath}/${moduleName}`
                        };
                    });

                    componentFiles = components.map(function(componentPath) {
                        return {
                            src: `${baseUIPath}/${componentPath}`,
                            dest: `${baseUIPath}/${componentPath.replace('.js', '.min.js')}`
                        };
                    });

                    files = [...files, ...componentFiles];

                    files.push({
                        src: grunt.file.expand({
                            filter: 'isFile'
                        }, [`${baseUIPath}/*.js`, ...ignoredSourceScriptPatterns]),
                        dest: `${baseUIPath}/poptart.min.js`
                    });

                    return files;
                }(),
                extDot: 'last',
                expand: true
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            },
            build: {
                cwd: 'presentation/static/ui/',
                src: ['**/*.css', '!css/jquery-ui/**', '!css/ionicons/**', '!**/*.min.js'],
                dest: 'presentation/static/ui/',
                ext: '.min.css',
                expand: true
            }
        },
        eslint: {
            options: {
                configFile: 'presentation/build/eslint.json',
                ignorePath: 'presentation/build/.eslintignore'
            },
            target: ['presentation/**/*.js', '!presentation/ui/scripts/*', '!presentation/static/**']
        },
        shell: {
            test: {
                command: 'python manage.py test -p "*tests.py"',
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    failOnError: true
                }
            }
        },
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            }
        },
        mochaTest: {
            unit: {
                options: {
                    reporter: 'spec'
                },
                src: ['presentation/test/server/*.js']
            }
        }
    });

    /*grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-eslint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');*/

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['lint', 'test']);
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['shell:test', 'mochaTest:unit', 'karma:unit']);
    grunt.registerTask('lint', ['eslint']);
    grunt.registerTask('build-static', ['uglify', 'copy', 'cssmin']);
};
```

And my dev dependencies from package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.7.1",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-eslint": "^19.0.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.13.2",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-shell": "^1.3.1",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.10.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jquery-chai": "^0.1.3",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.6",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0"
  }
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Using time-grunt to verify that loading tasks was actually the problem. It was. actually running tasks took very reasonable amounts of time.
2. using jit-grunt. This made no noticeable difference.
3. npm prune. This actually did make a fairly big (~30 seconds) difference, but still leaves me at a completely unreasonable time for task loading.
4. Removing and unloading some of the dependencies (uglify, copy, cssmin) I had added around the time that I started seeing this problem (originally, when I just had the testing/linting tasks, everything worked nice and fast). This also made no noticeable difference.

So. What else could be causing slowness on this scale?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are using a lot of testing frameworks there. Are you sure you need ALL of them?

Comment: I definitely don't, although these all serve their purpose. This is my sandbox app to play with things we might want to use on our actual product, so there are some random things here. In any event, they don't seem to be the core of the problem since they were all there back before I started seeing this slowness.

Comment: I would try commenting out each section one by one then see where the issue stops happening. Otherwise some basic stuff like deleting your `node_modules` folder then running `npm install` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the root cause of this was some inefficient file searching in the uglify task. I'd completely forgotten that I had made that giant blob of crazy and IEF, which explains why I was seeing the slowness even when I wasn't running the uglify task. I suppose it also explains why the time for the file search was getting lumped in with the loading tasks.

In any event, the main culprit was (predictably) where I was returning the source/dest paths for the dynamically found script modules, here:

```
                    return {
                        src: grunt.file.expand({
                            filter: 'isFile'
                        }, [`${baseUIPath}/${modulePath}/*.js`, ...ignoredSourceScriptPatterns]).sort(
                            function(a, b) {
                                return a.length - b.length;
                            }
                        ),
                        dest: `${baseUIPath}/${modulePath}/${moduleName}`
                    };
```

Unspurprising because it is in a loop. In any event, I noticed it was missing a cwd. Adding that cut the time down to 7s. Still needs improving, but at least now I know what to improve.

**Morals of this story:**

1. add cwd's when search for files
2. Maybe just don't search for files if you don't have to

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your Gruntfile and installed the dependencies manually, and the loading time of the Gruntfile was ~4 secs. Not fast, but not the minutes you talk about.

My guess is grunt.file.expand is working hard. Maybe `presentation/ui` folder is too big? What do you get by running `tree presentation/ui | wc -l` ? That shows the number of files you have there.

Otherwise, it would be helpful to also see your package.json and `npm ls` output.

Comment: I've updated my question with the dependency details from package.json. The full npm dependency tree was ridiculous, but I'm not sure what to do about that because hey, NodeJS.

Comment: the file.expand definitely seems to be a resource killer, and I know I need to do something to optimize that (I'm open to suggestions for how to dynamically map src and dest files). i have 73 files and 23 folders in presentation/ui, which definitely accounts for some slowness, but the times i'm seeing still seem excessive. Or maybe not - like I say, I only have so much experience with grunt. In any event, it'll be a lot worse than that when I go to implement this in our actual app instead of my play sandbox area.